# Convert string to string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Is there an easy way to convert a string into a string array?

For example, I have a string:

```
string s = "1234";
```

I want convert to this

```
string[] ss = {"1","2","3","4"};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `string.ToCharArray()` will make it a _char_ array. Is that what you're looking for? Here are the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `string[] ss = s.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to split the string into an array of `char`s then you can simply use:

```
char[] ss = s.ToCharArray();
```

If you want an array of `string`s instead of `char`s, you can simply use:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
string[] ss = s.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Here is a [runnable example](https://repl.it/@ivankahl/SplitString).

**UPDATE:** No need to call `.ToCharArray()` since the string is already enumerable as mentioned by canton7 below.